# unauthorized error when creating queue in event hubs

Tags: python, azure-eventhub, qpid

need to create queue in eventhub for receive messages sent to it using python,
but got this error when using the code below.

note : policy is set to send, listen.

thanks

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService

sbs = ServiceBusService("xxhubspacexx",
                        shared_access_key_name="xxpolicyxx",
                        shared_access_key_value="xxkeyvalxx")

sbs.create_queue("taskqueue") #AzureHttpError: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You call it Event Hubs but it's actually a Service Bus Queue. They are distinct services. Event Hubs have no queues.
2. The error message is quite clear I think: the shared access policy that you are using has permissions for Send and Listen, but no Manage permission which is required to create Service Bus queues.